# book for parabolic partial differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I need the book "Linear and quasilinear equations of parabolic type"  By Olʹga Aleksandrovna Ladyzhenskai͡a, Vsevolod Alekseevich Solonnikov, Nina N. Ural'tseva.The price range of the hard copy is beyond my reach.Can anyone share me a soft copy of the above title.Its urgent.

Comment: Sixty dollars is beyond your reach? http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/0821815733/ref=dp_olp_all_mbc?ie=UTF8&condition=all

Comment: Yes. Its a pretty big amount for a student in India.@TrialAndError